# CMD - Takeown giving "The data area passed to a system call is too small"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am writing a script to reset roaming profiles and it is failing at a part which basically:

1. Changes ownership of a Folder and subfolders (the user profile)
2. Copies it to a Temp folder
3. Removes the original

To change ownership I use takeown:

```
takeown /s \\profile-server /f e:\Profiles\%username% /r /d Y
```

This is run from a domain admin account so permissions are fine. I then get the following output:

> SUCCESS: The file (or folder): "\\profile-server\e$\Profiles\%username%" now owned by user "domain\user".
>
> ERROR: The data area passed to a system call is too small

So it changes ownership of the top most folder but fails at the first sub-item.

I have tried this on 2 computers on the network and it works fine but as soon as I change the computer to the profile server this error comes.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to rectify this all I had to do was use PsExec in order to run the command, so:

```
psexec \\profileserver takeown /f e:\Profiles\%username% /r /d Y
```

And it allowed me to recursively take ownership of all the files.