# Powershell :Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The data area passed to a system call is too small

Tags: powershell-3.0

Here is my code. The password section is fine. However, I get the error

`Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The data area passed to a system call is too small.`

When it runs. It references "Start-Process" line. What am I missing? This is a script to stop a service on a remote server using credentials I supplied.The code it is running is shown below as well

```
    $ServiceAccountAdmin= "Domain\ServiceAccount"
    $Password = Get-Content "C:\PSScripts\Passwords\ServiceAccount.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credential = New-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "$ServiceAccountAdmin",$Password

    Start-Process $PSHOME\Powershell.exe -Credential $Credential  "C:\PSScripts\Services\StopSMSAGent.ps1"
```

StopSMSAgent code:

```
    $SMSAgentHost = Get-WmiObject win32_service | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "CcmExec"}
    $SMSAgentHost.stopservice()
```

Comment: Hi, does it work with `Start-Process powershell -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList "-file 'C:\PSScripts\Services\StopSMSAGent.ps1'"` ?

Comment: No, still same error.

Comment: According to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753877/cmd-takeown-giving-the-data-area-passed-to-a-system-call-is-too-small this could be a permission issue. Do you have any overpowered admin account to test here ? And if you replace the contents of `StopSMSAGent.ps1` with a dummy command like `Get-Date` does it work ?

Comment: This whole thing started trying to create a Powershell script to run locally on a remote computer to start and stop a service. I wouldn't have to use Start Process if I could simply find a way to start and stop a service on a remote computer using local admin credentials.

For instance 

         Start-Service -Name AdobeARMservice

`Start-Service : Service 'Adobe Acrobat Update Service (AdobeARMservice)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot open AdobeARMservice 
service on computer '.'.`

Comment: I am running this in a Powershell command window with a local admin account and can't even figure out why the error. If I run PS as as administrator it works. How can no one ever document this issue?

Comment: I guess Windows CLI has to be "run as Administrator". This is made to prevent regular users from changing system settings and such.